# Creation of variable containing a df variable labels leads to the creation of "dot" variable name

Tags: r, data-analysis

How can I improve the syntax below to avoid the appearance of a dot when I try to save a dataset's variable list and relating variable labels to the dataframe vars.n.theirlabels. I haven't been able to remove the dot created by get_label.

```
   library(dplyr) 
   vars.n.theirlabels <- get_label(mtcars) %>%
   data.frame() %>%
   mutate(var.names = colnames(mtcars))  
   rownames(vars.n.theirlabels) <- NULL
   View(vars.n.theirlabels)
```

Edit: @Ben suggested that the data.frame() statement piped after the collection of the variable label with get_label caused the appearance of the dot as the variable name. The problem is solved by nesting these the two piped steps. The resulting variable name can be then renamed. Thanks again Ben!

```
library(dplyr) 
library(sjlabelled)
vars.n.theirlabels <- data.frame(get_label(mtcars)) %>%
   mutate(var.names = colnames(mtcars))  
   rownames(vars.n.theirlabels) <- NULL
names(vars.n.theirlabels)[1] <- "var.labels" 
  library(expss) 
  vars.n.theirlabels = apply_labels(vars.n.theirlabels,
                        var.names = "Variable name",
                        var.labels = "Variable label")
  View(vars.n.theirlabels)
```

Comment: Could you add which other package you are using for `get_label` such as `sjlabelled`? A quick look suggests that using `data.frame()` above after `get_label` without specifying a column name gives you a "dot" column name...

Comment: Apologies, yes, I had loaded the package sjlabelled. Thanks for the advice re data.frame() being the culprit for generating the dot. Can I specify data.frame(vars.n.theirlabels) instead of data.frame()? Or do I need to specify another name? You gave me something to work with in the meantime. Thanks again!

Comment: `get_label` returns a named character vector...you might want to try using `efc` [sample data](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjlabelled/articles/labelleddata.html) with labels for your example instead of mtcars to see what this might look like...something like `data.frame(var = get_label(efc))` will give you a column named `var` of labels and rownames containing variable names...if piped with `%>%` that would look like `get_label(efc) %>% data.frame(var = .)`

Comment: Thanks so much, your suggestion worked on the actual example in my question. Can I edit the question to acknowledge you and show what worked?

Comment: Absolutely, you can edit your question - you can also answer your own question too, so others can learn from this.

Comment: Thanks again Ben, edited and explained code changes.